# R: Conditional Replacement of values in several columns in data frame

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have read several posts on this but they all applied to only changing one column/variable. I need to replace values in a number of columns in a dataframe at once. I thought this should work but it's not and I cannot figure out why.

```
positive <- c("Yes", "Science")
temp1 <- c("Yes", "No","","Science", "Only-Child")
temp2 <- c("Yes", "No",""," Yay people!", "Pessimist")
temp3 <- cbind(temp1,temp2)
colnames(temp3) <- c("Feature1","Feature2")
temp <- as.data.frame(temp3)
```

This does not work:

```
for (i in temp) {
  ifelse(i %in% positive, 1, i)
}
```

However, doing it on one column works:

```
test <- ifelse(temp$Feature1 %in% positive, 1, temp$Feature1)
test
```

So I suspect the i is not what I want it to be but a check results in what I expected:

```
for (i in temp) {
  print(i %in% positive)
}
```

The output should look like this:

```
  Feature1     Feature2
         1            1
        No           No

         1  Yay people!
Only-Child    Pessimist
```

So what am I missing?

Comment: I think you're over-complicating the issue. It would help if you showed what you want the output to be

Comment: So, to be clear, you want to replace any instance of an element that exists in `positive` with 1?

Comment: Correct. and keep original value if it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that's causing problems in your example is the conversion of strings to factors. Assuming that's fixed, here's a way to get the appropriate indices and assign 1 to them:

```
temp <- as.data.frame(temp3, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
temp[apply(temp, 2, function(x) x %in% positive)] <- 1
```

Comment: Just posted the same thing. Thanks for the hint with factors!

Comment: I would've expected `df %in% positive` to work (because `df == "Yes"` does), but it doesn't :(

Comment: @hadley that was exactly my thought - `%in%` seems to cause me a lot of unexpected issues

Answer (score 1):

My answer is based on assumptions of what you asked, since you didn't specify what exactly it is you want the result to be.

Your loop tries return `ifelse(temp$Feature_i %in% positive, 1, temp$Feature_i)` for all `i`. However the code will try to return a vector with either `1` or the respective "column" of `temp` for each "column". This will not work, since ifelse is a vectorized function, meaning it can - as opposed to the `if` statement - support a vector of boolean variables as input (+1 for the question). But since each vectorized function returns a vector, all values within this vector will be of the same class (R does the conversion automatically). In your case `temp$Feature_i` is a vector of factors and the respective conversion to numeric is done by the index of the factor within the vector. Thus I am not able to understand your `ifelse` query.

If you want to change exactly those inputs in `temp` which contain `positive` and you want to know which elements to change (if that's your intention) then you'd have to start from the following (use `sapply` as that is usually faster then for loops):

```
sapply(temp, function(x) x %in% positive)
     Feature1 Feature2
[1,]     TRUE     TRUE
[2,]    FALSE    FALSE
[3,]    FALSE    FALSE
[4,]     TRUE    FALSE
[5,]    FALSE    FALSE
```

However if you strictly need the output you suggested in your third code block then do

```
sapply(temp, function(x) ifelse(x %in% positive,1,x))
```

Hth,
D

---

The solution is as follows:

```
sapply(temp, function(x) ifelse(x %in% positive,1,as.character(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

There probably is a scoping issue in the for-loop. Try

```
test <- (temp == "Yes" | temp == "Science")
```

(I assume you want true or false statements as output, right? If not, it might be good to add an example of how you want your final dataframe to look like.)

EDIT:

Converting it into a matrix first seems to help. Try:

```
ind <- (temp == "Yes" | temp == "Science")
tmp <- as.matrix(temp)
tmp[ind] <- 1
```

Comment: But I only want TRUE if the value is in positive and keep the original value if it is not.

Comment: See my edit. I got it to work by creating indices first and converting `temp` to a matrix.

Comment: That works! Through browsing I also found how to use apply here:     a <- function(x) ifelse(x %in% positive, 1, x)
apply(temp,2,a)